# Python Encode Special JSON characters when string contain regex?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-requests

Does anyone know of a way to get json.dumps to properly encode a string that contains a regular expression?  Or if there is an alternative way to encode data for a JSON payload that doesn't utilize json.dumps that will correctly handle this?

For example:

```
import json
MyString = 'regex "Network\sInformation:[\s\S]+?Workstation\sName:\t+(?<src_host>[^\r]+)"'
data = {}
data['MyString'] = MyString
data['date'] = '2017-09-18T11:28:06'  
json_data = json.dumps(data)
print json_data
```

Will generate:

```
{
    "date": "2017-09-18T11:28:06", 
    "MyString": "regex \"Network\\sInformation:[\\s\\S]+?Workstation\\sName:\t+(?<src_host>[^\r]+)\""
}
```

However, you'll notice that the `[^\r]` isn't properly escaped, should be `[^\\r]`, which when processed by the API results in a parse error.

In the end, the JSON payload I am building here will be submitted to a web API using requests, similar to this:

```
requests.post(url, auth=(uname, passwd), data=json_data, headers=headers)
```

Note:  I have considered simply creating a function that issues a bunch of replace commands to manually encode this myself, and this is my plan B at the moment, but I am hoping there is already a solution/module out there that I can utilize to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex definition is flawed, not the JSON output:

```
>>> MyString = 'regex "Network\sInformation:[\s\S]+?Workstation\sName:\t+(?<src_host>[^\r]+)"'
>>> MyString[-5:-4]
'\r'
>>> len(MyString[-5:-4])
1
>>> print(MyString[-5:-4])  # produces an empty line
```

You defined a carriage return, not a separate backslash and `r` character; Python interpreted the two as an escape sequence. JSON then encoded that carriage return with `\r` too:

```
>>> import json
>>> chr(13)  # ASCII code 13 is a carriage return
'\r'
>>> print(json.dumps(chr(13)))
"\r"
```

Use a raw string literal instead:

```
MyString = r'regex "Network\sInformation:[\s\S]+?Workstation\sName:\t+(?<src_host>[^\r]+)"'
```

Now you have two separate characters, `\` and `r`:

```
>>> MyString = r'regex "Network\sInformation:[\s\S]+?Workstation\sName:\t+(?<src_host>[^\r]+)"'
>>> MyString[-6:-4]
'\\r'
>>> len(MyString[-6:-4])
2
>>> print(MyString[-6:-4])
\r
```

and those two characters produce your expected JSON output:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(MyString))
"regex \"Network\\sInformation:[\\s\\S]+?Workstation\\sName:\\t+(?<src_host>[^\\r]+)\""
```